# boost::multi_index error "template argument 'x' is invalid"

Tags: c++, cross-platform, boost-multi-index

So I made some kind of database with boost_multi_index like this:

```
#include <boost\multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost\multi_index\ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost\multi_index\member.hpp>
using namespace boost::multi_index;
using namespace std;

struct list_entry{
    int id;
    string name;
    string* data;
};

typedef multi_index_container<list_entry,
    indexed_by<
        ordered_unique< tag<int>, member<list_entry, int, &list_entry::id>>,                // unique id
        ordered_unique< tag<string>, member<list_entry, string, &list_entry::name>>,        // unique name
        ordered_non_unique< tag<string*>, member<list_entry, string*, &list_entry::data>>   // some data associated with the id/name
    >
>table;

class Database
{
    private:    
        table music, names;
        typedef table::index<int>::type list_id;
        typedef table::index<string>::type list_string;

    //some more code here
};
```

and it compiles fine with Visual Studio 2010.

However I wanted to switch my project over to Code::Blocks with MinGW and it seems like he's not so happy with that, this is the compile log:

```
.\source\db.h|19|error: template argument 3 is invalid|
.\source\db.h|15|error: template argument 2 is invalid|
.\source\db.h|15|error: template argument 1 is invalid|
.\source\db.h|14|error: template argument 2 is invalid|
.\source\db.h|13|warning: 'typedef' was ignored in this declaration [enabled by default]|
.\source\db.h|24|error: 'table' does not name a type|
.\source\db.h|25|error: 'table' does not name a type|
.\source\db.h|26|error: 'table' does not name a type|
C:\Program Files\boost_1_54_0\boost\system\error_code.hpp|222|warning: 'boost::system::posix_category' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]|
C:\Program Files\boost_1_54_0\boost\system\error_code.hpp|223|warning: 'boost::system::errno_ecat' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]|
C:\Program Files\boost_1_54_0\boost\system\error_code.hpp|224|warning: 'boost::system::native_ecat' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]|
C:\Program Files\boost_1_54_0\boost\asio\error.hpp|244|warning: 'boost::asio::error::system_category' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]|
C:\Program Files\boost_1_54_0\boost\asio\error.hpp|246|warning: 'boost::asio::error::netdb_category' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]|
C:\Program Files\boost_1_54_0\boost\asio\error.hpp|248|warning: 'boost::asio::error::addrinfo_category' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]|
C:\Program Files\boost_1_54_0\boost\asio\error.hpp|250|warning: 'boost::asio::error::misc_category' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]|
C:\Program Files\boost_1_54_0\boost\asio\ssl\error.hpp|34|warning: 'boost::asio::error::ssl_category' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]|
C:\Program Files\boost_1_54_0\boost\asio\detail\winsock_init.hpp|116|warning: 'boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_instance' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]|
||=== Build finished: 7 errors, 10 warnings (0 minutes, 15 seconds) ===|
```

I'm completely clueless since the error is not any more specific than that and I couldn't find any related problem.

So I hope someone can give me an answer here, if more information is required I will edit it in afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by using BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER like this:

```
typedef multi_index_container<list_entry,
    indexed_by<
        ordered_unique< tag<int>, BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(list_entry, int, id)>,
        ordered_unique< tag<string>, BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(list_entry, string, name)>,
        ordered_non_unique< tag<string*>, BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(list_entry, string*, data)>
    >
>table;
```

Comment: This is strange... I suspect there's a name clashing issue with `member`, you can try explicitly qualifying as with `::boost::multi_index::member`

Comment: I previously tried qualifying everything explicitly as `boost::multi_index::` (without the leading `::`) and removing the `using namespace` line but the problem was still there. However after doing some more extensive search I found out about BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER which seems to be used when writing cross-platform code so I decided to try it out (and like I said, it works).

Comment: Well, the only situation where `BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER` would make a difference is if your compiler is so old as to have the `BOOST_NO_POINTER_TO_MEMBER_TEMPLATE_PARAMETERS` defect macro on. Can you check that?

Comment: ...wow it seems like back then I didn't use the -std=c++11 parameter for the compiler. If I remember correctly I solved the above problem like described, then I ran into other issues with my code and then I found out that the parameter was not set. So yeah, the original code compiles fine with the missing parameter.